# Changing Path using 'sed'

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to change the path using 'sed'

```
sed -i "s|METASPLOIT_PATH=/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3||METASPLOIT_PATH=/opt/metasploit-framework|g" config/set_config
```

but an error showed up which I am neither understanding nor expecting

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 51: unknown option to `s'
```

What does this mean??

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typo to me, you have a duplicate pipe character in the middle of the substitute expression.

The following command works:

```
sed -i "s|METASPLOIT_PATH=/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3|METASPLOIT_PATH=/opt/metasploit-framework|g" config/set_config
```

Answer (score 1):

there is two consecutive pipes in your command

try :

```
 sed -i "s|METASPLOIT_PATH=/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/msf3|METASPLOIT_PATH=/opt/metasploit-framework|g" config/set_config
```